# Redirect Play Framework 2 output to Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to set up Eclipse (Kepler) to work with Play Framework 2 (2.2.2 RC).

I've followed the docs and everything seems fine, the code is reloaded nicely and I can debug properly from Eclipse using a Java Remote Application configuration.

Thus far, after some hours of trials, the only (dreadful) problem is that I can't see any output printed onto the Eclipse console (and the application IS logging on the stout). Both the Play application and Eclipse are running on the same host.

The Java Remote Application configuration uses `Connection Type | Standard (Socket Attach)` and `Standard Input and Output | Allocate console`.

What should I do? Switching back and forth between the shell and the IDE is driving me crazy, not to say that I cannot click-track exception throw-points anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, this seems to work as an external tool configuration.  The only problem is the console doesn't recognize control-d, so you have to kill your java process from the task manager.

[image]

[image]