# Play Framework display output in console Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to see the output of the Play Framework console directly in the Eclipse console. Can anyone help me?

I set the debug and it is working properly. But would like to see the outputs of the Play Framework in Eclipse console

My question is this same topic: [Redirect Play Framework 2 output to Eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730926/redirect-play-framework-2-output-to-eclipse-console)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the other question and the Play docs, I'm not sure it's currently possible to do what you're asking.

You can run Play in debug mode which uses remote debugging in Eclipse: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE

Unfortunately, Play is still running in the Play Console process and it's going to print all logs and stdout into to that console. Eclipse is only listening on a port for JVM messages related to execution.

One hack you can do is alter the project configuration to add a file appender for the logging framework. You could then keep the log file open in Eclipse. You'll have to refresh the file or keep clicking on it to get new data, but it's something.

Another option is to ask the same question in the Play Google group. This is monitored more closely by the Play engineering team - https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/play-framework